# Need to generate file winmail.dat (Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format - TNEF) with attachment in Java

Tags: java, format, tnef

I want to generate file `winmail.dat` which in `TNEF` format with java.
Is there any Open Source library which I can use to create `TNEF` file.

I found one

> http://poi.apache.org/hmef/

but it is read only API for parse `TNEF` file.

Please let me know if there is any other API for Java or any other language by which I can reach my goal.